# scrapy image pipeline object has no attribute 'spiderinfo' error

Tags: python, scrapy

i just met an issue with scrupy image pipeline, the background is i just want to download some pics for testing purpose with scrupy image pipeline, but after the code composed, i met an error when i run the script

**error message:**

```
2021-12-31 17:07:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'image_urls': ['https://pic01.jituwang.com/190328/256612-1Z32Q1453861-lp.jpg']}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 859, in _runCallbacks
    current.result, *args, **kwargs
  File "e:\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 150, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "e:\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\media.py", line 86, in process_item
    info = self.spiderinfo
AttributeError: 'ImgPileine' object has no attribute 'spiderinfo'
```

**command to run the script:**

`scrapy crawl picspider`

**scrupy version:**

Scrapy 2.5.1

**here's the code below**

```
#spider.py
import scrapy
from picscrapydemo.items import PicscrapydemoItem

class PicspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'picspider'
    start_urls = ['http://www.jituwang.com/bizhi/qiche/']

    def parse(self, response):
        pics_src = response.xpath('//div[@class="anPic"]//img/@src').extract()
        for pic_src in pics_src:
            item=PicscrapydemoItem()
            item['image_urls']=[pic_src]
            # print(pic_src)
            yield item

#pipelines.py
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
import scrapy

class ImgPileine(ImagesPipeline):


    def open_spider(self, spider):
        print('start')

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        url=request.url
        file_name=url.split('/')[-1]
        return file_name

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        return item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the function `open_spider`.

Replace it with:

```py
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.spiderinfo = self.SpiderInfo(spider)
        print('start')
```

Comment: it's working, thanks :)